# Regex matcher work on JUnit but fails on a Servlet container

Tags: java, regex

This is my test String

```
-----------------------------12303134546862
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="notepad.html"
Content-Type: text/html
```

And I have a Java Regex code to get the "boundary" part, which is the  `-----------------------------12303134546862`

```
String BOUNDARY_PATTERN = "(\\A-+(.)+\\n)";
String byteString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(BOUNDARY_PATTERN);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(byteString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String boundary = matcher.group(1);
    contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
}
```

When running using JUnit test the matcher matches group 1, but when running inside Tomcat server/servlet the `boundary` is null, thus matcher did not work.

What could be the possible problem that might be causing this?

Comment: Capturing a dot one or more times is not efficient and probably is not what you meant. Try `"(?m)\\A-+\\d+$"` and get `.group(0)` value.

Comment: Thanks that worked, if you can make it into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: You accepted a `"(?m)^-+\\d+$"` solution that will match any line that starts with 1 or more `-`s and ends with 1+ digits. `\A` would only let match the first line matching this pattern. It is now not clear what you really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably because you’re not at the very start of input, which is what `\A` matches.

Try using multi-line flag and the normal start anchor:

```
"(?m)^-+\\d+$"
```

With the multi line flag on, `^` and `$` match start and end of each *line*, rather than start and end of the whole input.